# Is it possible to restrict a user to only open certain programs in Windows 7 Starter Edition?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I need to set a up a computer that can only use the browser and lock it to a single webpage. He cannot be able to install or use any other program. Is this possible with Windows 7 Starter Edition? If not what edition allows it, do programs that can help me do this exist? (Either free or paid.)

Comment: Is Windows a requirement or a preference?

Comment: Windows is a requirement :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows versions Pro and up at least, with access to Local Policy (similar to Group Policy from servers) can invoke gpedit.msc from a Run prompt, can be set to run a program other than explorer.exe as a "shell." So they would start that program instead of the "Windows environment" with desktop/start menu etc. Internet Explorer can be launched as this shell (the full path to iexplore.exe should be used instead of explorer.exe). There is a registry key that can be used to do this as well, though I'm not sure what the minimum version of Windows is for using this key. It's located at:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon --> Shell

(from an [autoit forum post](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/121912-windows-shell-registry-key/))

There are third party tools that can do this as well. Microsoft discontinued their lockdown tool that was free (and it only supports up through Windowx XP or possibly Vista, no 7). However, [Fortres Grand](http://www.fortresgrand.com/) and other similar software like [Faronics Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/) offers more control of restrictions and can also wipe the computer back to how it was at the last reboot for example, no matter what the user does (they can limit what runs as well). I'm unsure if they work with Windows 7 Starter Edition though, they likely require Home Premium.